# How to check if visitor is from referrals with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say my site is example.com people can visit by directly type in "example.com" in the browser to open it up.

However I want to check if people visit my site from other sources, like google or other referrals. Then I'd like to add jquery modal for those visitors. Is it doable? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need JQuery; just JavaScript. The document.referrer property, which will give you the site where the visitor was just before example.com, should do the trick for you.

```
var referrer = document.referrer;
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.referrer)

Comment: Ow, and a side-note: know that referrer's are generated _client_ side, so they're not 100% correct all the time. They can be easily faked or removed (for privacy or less nice reasons)

Answer (score 0):

[Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) also provide this referral information, you just apply an account, add a script right before your body tag.

```
<script>
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'FILL-IN-YOUR-ACCOUNT']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();
</script>
```

Comment: But he wouldn't be able to react on this for that visitor, it's only anlisation afterward? Doesn't seem like what @ray is looking for?